# Azure datafactory V2- activity run slices are not visible

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have created pipeline in ADF V2. Pipeline consists of lookup - Copy- Custom.

The pipeline source code is correct and gets validated. But I am not able to see the activity slices in Monitor Pipeline window. What changes to be made?
[image]

[image]

Also, how to delete pipeline from portal? The delete option deleted the pipeline from the list, but when I tried creating pipeline with same name, it failed

[image]

Comment: Did you run your pipeline in debug mode or with trigger?

Comment: I triggered it..

Comment: Could you press F12, and check is there any error in console tab?

Comment: This error i got in F12 window.. GET https://graph.windows.net/me/thumbnailPhoto?api-version=1.6 404 (Not Found)

Comment: This error doesn't matter actually. What is your pipeline status? is it succeeded or failed?

Comment: The status of pipeline is failed within 2seconds..

Comment: I think i find the problem. Please go to All tab instead of the cancelled tab in your activity runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your question about how to delete:
After deleting it, you need click "publish all" button to sync your change to your data factory.

For the activity run not visible issue:
Please switch to "All" tab. Currently, you are in "Cancelled" tab.

Comment: I did the sync option also. But i was not able to create pipeline with same name again.

Comment: Did you try refresh button or just press F5 to refresh the entire portal? Does the deleted pipeline show out again?

Comment: No it does not show any pipeline in list after browser refresh. But is the reference of pipeline stored in cache? If yes then how long it is stored in cache?

Comment: It should not be cached. Are you in Git mode or data factory mode? I just tried in my data factory, it worked well. What is your error message? Could you share me the screen shot?

Comment: This option is working now for me. But the activities are not displayed in pipeline run as shown in above snapshots.

Comment: @FangLiu off-topic question: When will be final version of ADF released? I heard something July

Comment: @DraganB. Sorry, I can’t give an official answer for your question. If you are asking for GA date, this is a related post. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/944830a6-f0b4-4dbb-9d6a-39ed2c3897a4/timeline-for-general-availability-ga-of-data-factory-v2?forum=AzureDataFactory

Comment: @FangLiu yes of course, sorry. But there is a lot of bugs with publish button from portal when using adf with vsts, wanted to see is there a final release near :) 
sorry for off topic question.

Comment: You are welcome to use the feedback in the portal to report any issue you hit. The prod team will actively fix them.